# Echo function jumping outside of Div

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

I have create a function for gettext translations, which is in a header file:

```
function _ex($text){
  echo gettext($text);
}
```

when I use the function _ex(""); it translates whatever text is in that function, which works great, though when I use it inside another function whith a div inside like so:

```
    echo '
          <div class="row row-centered">
          <div class="col-md-3"></div>
          <div class="col-md-5">
          <div class="alert alert-danger">
          <strong>' . _ex("Oh snap!"). '</strong> You are banned. <b><u>Do not</u></b> register another account
          <br>Reason you are banned: <b><u>'.$banneduser->reason.'</u></b>
          </div>
          </div>
          </div>';
```

It for some reason jumps outside of the div col-md-5 and ends up displaying like so:

[image: div]

It is working in some other files, just not this. I have ' . _ex("") . ' so it works inside of the echo. Is there a reason behind this, does the opening quotes cancel the div? Is it because it's being echoed twice? What is a way to stop this without having to rewrite all of my code? End the first echo, then use the function and reopen another echo? Is there a function for this, to check if it's already been echoed if it has just return it rather than echo?

Comment: i think this happens because the alert class doesn't inherit the implementations of its parent div.  can you open the inspect element for google chrome browser and check the alert div. try changing the positioning of the alert element. like changing it to fixed. but make sure to add adjustments to center it like some padding.

Comment: @Gokigooooks Not a bootstrap issue. [See this sandbox.](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b94bcbf20774af04fcf6d4fd64a5d7949819b518) Note how the "something" ends up before the "hello world" altogether.

Comment: yes you are right! but you can also work around this by changing the css of bootstrap for alert. but yeah you adressed his question better. thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you call `_ex("Oh snap!")` inside of another `echo`, you are doing this:

```
echo 'Some text' . echo 'Oh snap!' . 'more text';
```

This can yield unpredictable results since the concatenated `echo` will fully execute first, then the contained `echo` will finish. [Demo here.](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b94bcbf20774af04fcf6d4fd64a5d7949819b518) Change your `_ex` function to something like this:

```
function _ex($text){
  return gettext($text);
}
```

And always call `_ex` like this:

```
echo _ex('Oh snap!');
```

Or with concatenation, you can now use the first line in my answer, or your own code in your question as desired.

The only alternatives to preserve existing code is to write a new function for concatenated statements:

```
function _exx($text) {
    return gettext($text);
}
```

Add another parameter to the `_ex` function to work with contexts (similar to how [`print_r` does it](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php):

```
function _ex($text, $return = false) {
    if ($return) {
        return gettext($text);
    }
    echo gettext($text);
}
```

Then call with:

```
echo 'Some text' . _ex("Oh snap!", true) . ' more text';
```

Or rewrite your existing echo:

```
echo '
          <div class="row row-centered">
          <div class="col-md-3"></div>
          <div class="col-md-5">
          <div class="alert alert-danger">
          <strong>';
_ex("Oh snap!");
echo '</strong> You are banned. <b><u>Do not</u></b> register another account
          <br>Reason you are banned: <b><u>'.$banneduser->reason.'</u></b>
          </div>
          </div>
          </div>';
```

But the first and second option is the "best practice" - you shouldn't be using `echo` in function calls since it causes these very problems in your question.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking that, but every word on mysite is pulled like _ex("") which would mean rewriting a lot of code, I could probably end the echo beofre the _ex and then start it again after it.

Comment: @johnsmith That is your only alternative.

Comment: @johnsmith I've added a few other alternatives in my edit though

Comment: Eventually, I will probably find all _ex and replace with echo _ex via notepad++

Answer (score 1):

Replace `echo` in your `_ex` function with `return`:

```
function _ex($text){
  return gettext($text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try concatenate string end echo end result:

```
$html = '
          <div class="row row-centered">
          <div class="col-md-3"></div>
          <div class="col-md-5">
          <div class="alert alert-danger">
          <strong>' . _ex("Oh snap!"). '</strong> You are banned. <b><u>Do not</u></b> register another account
          <br>Reason you are banned: <b><u>'.$banneduser->reason.'</u></b>
          </div>
          </div>
          </div>';

echo $html;
```

Comment: Still the same, still moves outside of the div.

Comment: @johnsmith I see you updated your question, yep stick with the other answers then and change your `_ex()` function to `return` and not `echo` if you do so, I would recommend to concatenate string untill you've got all the parts you need and echo only the entire "element" you want..